# Vertical textbox in SSRS report does not show in production, shows in PDF export and printed mode

Tags: reporting-services

I have SSRS report that has an address label in vertical mode so that it will fit in an 8.5 x 11 envelope address window.

It only shows on my development box, and on the SSRS production server if exported as a .PDF or just printed.

It does not show in browser after report is run. Only in .PDF and print mode.

---

[image: No Address shows]

[image: Address example in .pdf and print mode]

---

Here is the XML for the report and relative area:

```
<Textbox Name="txtAddressLabel">
  <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
  <Paragraphs>
    <Paragraph>
      <TextRuns>
        <TextRun>
          <Value>=UCASE(Replace(Fields!CL_FirstName.Value, " ","") &amp; " " &amp; Replace(Fields!CL_MI.Value," ","") &amp; " " &amp; Replace(Fields!CL_LastName.Value, " " ,"") &amp; vbCrLF &amp; TRIM(Fields!Mail_Addr1.Value) &amp; IIF(TRIM(Fields!Mail_Addr2.Value)="","",vbCrLf &amp; Trim(Fields!Mail_Addr2.Value)) &amp; vbCrLf &amp; TRIM(Fields!Mail_City.Value) &amp; ", " &amp; Fields!Mail_State.Value &amp; " " &amp; Fields!Mail_Zip.Value)</Value>
          <Style>
            <FontFamily>Verdana</FontFamily>
          </Style>
        </TextRun>
      </TextRuns>
      <Style />
    </Paragraph>
  </Paragraphs>
  <Top>0.36313in</Top>
  <Left>6.56734in</Left>
  <Height>2.625in</Height>
  <Width>0.98095in</Width>
  <ZIndex>3</ZIndex>
  <Style>
    <Border>
      <Style>None</Style>
    </Border>
    <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
    <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
    <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
    <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
    <WritingMode>Rotate270</WritingMode>
  </Style>
</Textbox>
```

Comment: Is the font style the same for the missing textbox as the items that are shown?

Comment: Why must a report that is meant to be printed be displayed in the browser?

Comment: Because there are multiple reports, for one, and the user occasionally wants to only print a couple of those. For two, the users are challenged enough to think it is not working.

Comment: The font is the same style, one size less than main text on report

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen this a lot and the solution was to toggle CanGrow on the cell (I can't remember if true or false was the culprit). 
Alternatively, it could be forced off the page? Have you tried putting a rectangle around it?